# All possible combinations of a,b,c,d (lenght 4) with conditions (java)

Tags: java, if-statement, char, multiple-conditions

So I need this algorithm to work but I can't seem to find where the problem is... I need to print all the possible combinaison of [a,b,c,d] (with a lenght of 4) with some condition (already in the algorithm). So what am I missing ? I'm still a begginer in Java, so thanks a lot for your help !

```
public class Test {

//Method saying that 'a' always have to follow 'b'
public static boolean aFollowsB(String s) {
      char[] set1 = s.toCharArray();

      for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        // If B is the last char, A can't possilby follow
        if (i == set1.length - 1) {
          if (set1[i] == 'b') { return false; }
        // Else if we encounter B, make sure next is an A
        } else {
          if (set1[i] == 'b') {
            if (set1[i+1] != 'a') { return false; }
          }
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

//Method saying that we can't have 'a' and 'd' in the same string
    public static boolean hasOnlyAOrD(String s) {
      char[] set1 = s.toCharArray();

      boolean hasA = false;
      boolean hasD = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        if (set1[i] == 'a') {
          hasA = true;
        } else if (set1[i] == 'd') {
          hasD = true;
        }
      }

      if (hasA && hasD) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

//Method printAllKLength to print all possible strings of k lenght
    static void printAllKLength(char[] set, int k) { 
        int n = set.length;  
        printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k); 
    } 

    static void printAllKLengthRec (char[] set,  
                                   String prefix,  
                                   int n, int k) 
    { 

        if (k == 0)  {
            System.out.println(prefix); 
              System.out.println(prefix);
            return; 

        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];  
            printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix,  
                                    n, k - 1);  
        } 
    } 
    //Method to print with the conditions
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] set1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}; 
        int k = 4; 
        if (aFollowsB(set1) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix)) {
            printAllKLength(set1, k); 
            }
```

}}

**EDIT**

Ok, so thanks to some help, I changed my code to a way more simple one, but now instead of giving me an error, it gives me nothing. I don't know what's missing.
Here's the new code :

```
//// Méthode principale printAllKLength pour imprimer tous les strings possible de longueur k

static void printAllKLength(char[] set, int k) { 
    int n = set.length;  
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k); 
} 

static void printAllKLengthRec (char[] set,  
                               String prefix,  
                               int n, int k) 


{    if (k == 0)  {
    if  (aFollowsB(prefix) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix) == true ) {
        System.out.println(prefix); 
        return; 

    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];  
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix,  
                                n, k - 1);  
    } }}



//Création de la méthode permettant de dire que 'a' doit toujours suivre 'b'

public static boolean aFollowsB(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') > str.indexOf('b');
}


    //Création de la méthode permettant de dire qu'on ne peut avoir 'a' et 'd' dans la même string
public static boolean hasOnlyAOrD(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') == -1 || str.indexOf('d') == -1;
}

//Création de la méthode principale

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] set1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}; 
    int k = 4; 
    printAllKLength(set1, k);
```

}}

Comment: Please describe the problem (instead of just saying it does not work).

Comment: All combinations of `{a,b,c,d}` is a, b, c or d followed by all combinations of the remaining letters.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix printAllKLengthRec:

Don't print everything twice (so remove one of the system.out's):

```
static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Then, call aFollowsB for each result (not in the main method where it is only called once):

```
static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (aFollowsB(prefix)) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        }
        return;
    }
    ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] set1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    int k = 4;
    printAllKLength(set1, k);
}
```

This means aFollowsB will take a String argument, and maybe look like this:

```
public static boolean aFollowsB(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') > str.indexOf('b');
}
```

Finally, do the same thing for hasOnlyAOrD (might wanna rename that method)

```
public static boolean hasOnlyAOrD(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') == -1 || str.indexOf('d') == -1;
}

static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (aFollowsB(prefix) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix)) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        }
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Then consider using the 'public' and 'static' keywords a lot less. But I guess that is out of scope for your assignment.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I made an edit on my question because there's still something I don't get.

Comment: If you format your code (ctrl+shift+f in Eclipse) you'll see that in printAllKLengthRec, the for loop is inside the k==0 if statement, which it shouldn't be. You have one line with three } . Move one one them above the for statement, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed this part, but it gave me an error :
` {    if (k == 0)  {
  if  (aFollowsB(prefix) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix) == true ) {
         System.out.println(prefix); 
         return; 
     
     } }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];  
         printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix,  
                                 n, k - 1);  
     } }`

Comment: The error being :<br/> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError<br/>
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449)<br/>
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)<br/>
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:113)<br/>
 at asASsS.A.printAllKLengthRec(A.java:26)<br/>
 at asASsS.A.printAllKLengthRec(A.java:27)<br/> The last one being repeted a lot.

Comment: Strange. Is the "return" statement in the right place. It should be inside the k==0 if statement, but not inside the aFollowsB&&hasOnlyAOrD if statement.